# Why gl 32-bit doesn't work on archlinux, amd card?

Tags: archlinux, steam, glx

```
$ glxinfo32 
name of display: :0
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
```

I found this from steam "glxChooseVisual failed".

```
$ steam
...
glXChooseVisual failed
glXChooseVisual failedsrc/steamUI/Main.cpp (409) : Assertion Failed: Fatal Error: glXChooseVisual failed
```

glxinfo32 and other 32bit demos didn't work, but 64bit demos worked.

```
$ glinfo
GL_VERSION: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.3.3
GL_RENDERER: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.42.0, 5.15.13-arch1-1, LLVM 13.0.0)
GL_VENDOR: AMD
...

$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
...
```

Here are some other errors.

```
$ glinfo32

freeglut (glinfo32):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
```

I learnt that mesa 11.x.y causes segfault but mine is 21.3.3.

```
$ glxgears_fbconfig32 
zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  glxgears_fbconfig32
```

I tried to reinstall mesa and other libs.

```
$ pacman -Qs mesa
local/glu 9.0.2-1
    Mesa OpenGL Utility library
local/lib32-glu 9.0.2-1
    Mesa OpenGL utility library (32 bits)
local/lib32-mesa 21.3.3-1
    An open-source implementation of the OpenGL specification (32-bit)
local/lib32-mesa-demos 8.4.0-3
    Mesa demos (32-bit)
local/lib32-mesa-utils 8.4.0-3
    essential Mesa utilities (32-bit)
local/lib32-opencl-mesa 21.3.3-1
    OpenCL support for AMD/ATI Radeon mesa drivers (32-bit)
local/mesa 21.3.3-2
    An open-source implementation of the OpenGL specification
local/mesa-demos 8.4.0-6
    Mesa demos
local/mesa-utils 8.4.0-6
    essential Mesa utilities
local/opencl-mesa 21.3.3-2
    OpenCL support for AMD/ATI Radeon mesa drivers
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I had `lib32-libdrm-git` and `libdrm` installed, which appeared to have different versions (2.4.109-1 and 2.4.66-1).

Try re-installing libdrm and lib32-libdrm.

Comment: Thanks! But they are already 2.4.109-1. `glxChooseVisual failed` remains after re-installing

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a custom built llvm and not the standard-shipped-one? Seems that your lib32-mesa can't find fbconfig.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31100527)